# Scope block ArgumentError with associations.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a join table between Folders and Emails, and I have a user_id also in my join tables model. In essence:

```
class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :folder_emails,
           :class_name => "FolderEmail"

  has_many :emails, ->(user) { where user_id: user.id }, :through => :folder_emails
end
```

So, when I try to do `Folder.find(1)`, I get the error:
`ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2)`

I'm new to the -> scope block syntax, and I can't comprehend why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Is there an association for User?

Comment: I assumed I was just supposed to pass in user. For example, if a = Folder.find(1), then a.emails(user) should suffice, where I pass in said user.

Answer (score 0):

Its kind a confusing, you cannot pass on the user id to scope. Scope can only work with defined set of known values in where.

Comment: What do you mean by defined set of known values? user_id is defined in the model I'm going to be searching in. If I can't do user.id, then can't I just do `->(id) { where user_id: id }`?

Comment: Ok, then how will you pass on the id to scope?

Comment: The way I understand it, where I decide to use the `emails` association, I just pass it a parameter now, which would be `id` in this case. For example, `a_folder.emails(3)`.